# Why it is recommended to run load test in non gui mode in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm monitoring the connect time and latency to connect from jmeter machine while running in GUI mode and that is in within acceptable limit.

Should we strictly follow non GUI mode even though I can able to perform load test with GUI mode?

I'm targeting 250 TPS and able to achieve that ..I have increased my memory and monitoring CPU and memory of load generator is below 60%.

Should I go for non GUI mode ?

Answer (score 1):

The main limitation is that each event in the [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) is being handled by a single event dispatch thread which will act as the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) on your JMeter side.

My expectation is that your "250 TPS" look like:

[image]

while it should look like:

[image]

So check how does your load pattern look like using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener (installable via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/))

Also check how does your JVM look like especially when it comes to [garbage collection](https://stackify.com/what-is-java-garbage-collection/), it can be done via i.e. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), most probably you will see the same "chainsaw" pattern

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to follow JMeter [best practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), **but**

you may encounter issues to achieve specifc goals (as TPS)

- your machine can't execute GUI or have low resources
- you execute JMeter using a script or build tool as Jenkins

Also it's better to be familiar with JMeter CLI (non GUI) and its [report capabilities](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

> JMeter supports dashboard report generation to get graphs and statistics from a test plan.

Also it will be needed for using distributed  testing

> consider running multiple CLI JMeter instances on multiple machines using distributed mode (or not)

CLI also useful for [Parameterising tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#parameterising_tests)

> The "loops" property can then be defined on the JMeter command-line:

> ```
> jmeter … -Jloops=12
> ```

Comment: But I'm able to achieve my target TPS in GUI mode..and I'm not interested in CLI mode report.. I want to understand what other limitations that may come when running in gui mode

Comment: @Mani currently you can and it's ok, but after you add more requests, more TPS you will reach a lower limit than non GUI mode, also some computer can't execute GUI mode and you can't/hard to use JMeter properties per execution